# Two Dimensional Array, Match-3 Type of Game

Tags: python, arrays

I'm still fairly new to Python and have been working on a project where I have to make a Match-3 type of game, where **3 or more** of the same color "jewels" would disappear.

Say I have a 2-D Array where each sublist is an column of the board.

```
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0]]
```

In this case, the board would be 5 columns and 4 rows.  The 0's are placeholders for the jewels, so say the board instead looked like:

```
[[0,0,0,0],
 [0,R,0,0],
 [0,R,0,0],
 [0,R,0,0],
 [0,R,0,0]]
```

Where R is equal to the color of the jewel.  How can I make a function that finds horizontal matches? How would I go about this by assuming that the board is filled with way more jewels.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more clarity to the question ? Did you mean 3 or more horizontal matches ? And what does disappear mean ? does it mean that the jewels disappear from the board & are marked as 0 ? And output is what is left on the board ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what the game logic would be however if you wanna find out if 3 consecutive elements of the column are same, you could use a logic like this:

```
test = [[0,0,0,0],
       [0,'R',0,0],
       [0,'R',0,0],
       [0,'R',0,0],
       [0,'R',0,0]]

def find_3consecutives_in_cols(game_matrix, n_rows, column_number):
    game_ls = []
    for i in range(n_rows):
        game_ls.append(game_matrix[i][column_number])
        print any(i==j==k for i, j, k in zip(game_ls, game_ls[1:], game_ls[2:]))

find_3consecutives_in_cols(test, n_rows=5, column_number=1)
False
False
False
True
True
```

This can help you find if there are 3 consecutive same values in any column. You could use a similar logic for rows too. Ensure you enter the correct number of columns while coding for rows. Since you have 4 consecutive 'R' in 2nd column you have 2 Trues.

I am not returning any value, just printing it. If you need to return a value, use return instead of print.

Hope this helps